# How can I create a .deb package with my compiled OpenCV build?

Tags: debian, compiling, opencv

OpenCV 2.4.2 took 6 hours to compile on the Raspberry Pi and I'd love to package everything up as a deb but I have never done that before. How can I package the compiled files so that they download or include the necessary other libraries?

Comment: Is this more a Linux specific question rather than a Pi related one? Maybe better asking on Debain about it?

Comment: Hi there. Since this is generic Debian, would you mind if I moved this to [ubuntu.SE] or [unix.SE]?

Comment: @Jivings I think it is PI related since I don't know anything about hard float vs soft float and I know there are caveats with Pi regarding that. If there is a general consensus that someone there could help answer this question I have no problem with it being moved

Comment: This page should have all of the information and tutorials you need: http://wiki.debian.org/Packaging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by OpenCV you mean the computer vision libraries at http://opencv.willowgarage.com/ then they are already packaged for debian by the Debian Science Team.

Your best bet is to download the debianised source package from your nearest debian mirror, modify the debian/rules and/or Makefile or configure etc as needed to compile correctly on the raspberry pi and rebuild the packages.

The packaging work is already done, there's no need to do it again....and again and again every time your want to update them.

There's a whole bunch of binary packages, but libopencv-dev is probably what you want to start with http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libopencv-dev

Comment: Will the published packages work on an ARM architecture like the Raspberry Pi?  I wish I better understood packages and dependencies but it would seem to me that unless willowgarage released a package specifically for the processor in the Raspberry Pi then their packages will not work.

Comment: You must have misread what I wrote.  I said to download the debian **SOURCE** packages and recompile for Raspberry Pi.  'onlinemarketresults' already has a RPi compilation (or cross-compilation) environment set up and knows how to compile for RPi, he just wanted to know how to make a package.

Answer (score 14):

I thought I would add a better answer for anyone else observing this thread.

So, if you've already gone through the trouble of building opencv on the device, you've probably followed the instructions here:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html

In which case, if you don't add the `-D args` to dynamically override CMake parameters in step two and you instead just run `cmake ..` inside the build directory (you created), it will generate a `CMakeCache.txt` file.

If you edit the `CMakeCache.txt` file, you can change:

`CPACK_BINARY_DEB:BOOL=ON`

...in addition to the other specified variables in the above opencv link. Instead of running `make` or `make install`... just run `make package` and the magic happens.

*Warning:* If you have `WITH_CUDA:BOOL=ON` you may have dependency issues with the packager - and that's a totally different question...

For more info see the `CPACK_*_*:BOOL` parameters in the cmake files, and consult the CPack documentation:

http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:CPackPackageGenerators

Comment: This produces a couple of .deb files, a couple of tar files and a script.  Which of these need to be distributed to and run on a target system? All?  Do they need any supporting files?

Comment: @Alex, forgot about this post last year. So, you should have `OpenCV-*-{libs,dev}.deb` 
You need both. I think dev has the headers ld uses to link against the .so in libs. You can also figure this out by running `dpkg -c OpenCV-*.deb` on the package, to list the contents.
Also, if you created this from source.tar, you may not have a version number and `dpkg -i $pkg` will not like this. You can tell if it says `OpenCV-unknown-*{dev,libs}.deb` In which case `git clone github.com/Itseez/opencv` and `git checkout $tag` in the releases tab. If you build from top of tree, you also get tag on deb.

Comment: No need to edit the CMakeCache.txt file manually...just rerun cmake with the right arg, i.e. `cmake -DCPACK_BINARY_DEB=ON ..`.  or  use the ccmake user interface.